# Show that $a^{n}$ is not bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis

> Hint is to use the Binomial theorem $(1+(a-1))^{n}$.

The first thing that comes to mind, is to prove that the sequence is increasing, which I proved. Then I should use proof by contradiction to prove that there isn't an upper limit.

So assume $x$ is the an upper limit. Then $x>a^{n}$ for all $n$. I know that I somehow need to show that there exists an $a^{n+1}$ such that $a^{n+1}>x$ and so $x$ is not an upper limit. I don't know how to use the binomial theorem to proceed from there.

Comment: What about $a=1$?

Answer (score 3):

We need to assume something about $a$. For example, $a\gt 1$ will do. Let $a=1+c$. Then by the Binomial Theorem $a^n=(1+c)^n\ge 1+nc$. And it is clear that $1+nc$ can be made arbitrarily large by choosing a large enough $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement only holds if $|a| > 1$. First use induction to prove Bernoulli's inequality: For $x \geq -1$ and $n \in \mathbb N$,
$$(1 + x)^n \geq 1 + nx.$$
For positive $a$, set $x = a - 1$. The right-hand side of the inequality can be made as large as we need. For negative $a$, note that $ a^{2n} = (-a)^{2n}$.

Comment: We didn't cover Bernoulli's inequality, could there be another way to do this? Otherwise, this is perfect.

Comment: One way or another you will use Bernoulli, either by induction or by using the binomial expansion and terminating it after the linear term.