# Show that sequence is not bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I wish to show that the sequence $q^n$ with $q > 1$ is not bounded above with this definition:
$\forall T \in \mathbb{R}: \exists n_T \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n\geq n_T: q^n \geq T$.

How can I use that to show that $q^n$ is not bounded above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $a^{n}$ is not bounded above?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440563/show-that-an-is-not-bounded-above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $T\leqslant 1$ yo can take $n_{T}=0$, because if $n\geqslant n_{T}$, then  $q^{n}\geqslant q^{n_{T}}=q^{0}=1\geqslant T$.

Now, if $T>1$ consider $x=\log_{q}(T)$ which is a positive real number because $T>1$, then consider $n_{T}\in \mathbb{N}$ the firt natural number greater than $x$. If $n\geqslant n_{T}$ then $q^{n}\geqslant q^{n_{T}}\geqslant q^{x}=T$.

Thats all.